# Hgignore everything except, regardless of directory

Tags: mercurial

I've seen the posts for hgignore everything except, but I can't seem to transform the regex to work with *subdirectories* as well.

```
syntax: regexp
(?<!\.cfm)$
```

Works for the root directory but not subdirs/subsubdirs. I don't want to manually specify those.

This is what I see **without** the ignore:

```
>hg stat
? document.cfm
? document.txt
? subdir1\document.cfm
? subdir1\document.txt
? subdir1\subsubdir1\document.cfm
? subdir1\subsubdir1\document.txt
? subdir2\document.cfm
? subdir2\document.txt
```

This is what I see **with** the ignore:

```
>hg stat
M .hgignore
? document.cfm
```

This is what I **want** to see:

```
>hg stat
? document.cfm
? subdir1\document.cfm
? subdir1\subsubdir1\document.cfm
? subdir2\document.cfm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired action is impossible. Python only does fixed-width negative lookups. Closing this question. Thanks to anyone who looked into it.

Comment: I think this answer is either misleading, wrong or outdated. Python definitely supports negative lookaheads `(?!.*foo)` but it doesn't support `(?<!foo.*)`. Please update your answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a file overrides ignores, so for the .hgignore if you've already added it you don't need to worry about including it.  That makes this much easier.

```
syntax: regexp
(?<!\.cfm)$
```

assuming that what you were trying to do is ignore everything except `.cfm` files.  Example:

```
% hg stat --all
A .hgignore
I adir/file.cfm
```

In general, don't overcomplicate the regex lines -- if you're (un)ignoring two different categories of things use two lines.

Comment: In your stat command the file.cfm is I for Ignored. I want my subdirectory .cfm files to be ? unknown, not ignored. This regex only grabs current level directory items.

Comment: Sorry, can you modify the original question to clearly describe what you want ignored and what you don't want ignore, preferably with examples, and we can get this sorted out quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible judging by how python only does fixed-width negative lookups..