# .hgignore a folder except some subfolders

Tags: regex, mercurial, tortoisehg, regex-negation

I want to ignore a folder but preserve some of its folders.
I Tried regexp matching like this

```
syntax: regexp
^site/customer/\b(?!.*/data/.*).*
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work.
I read in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8651846/968734) that python only does fixed-width negative lookups.

Is my desired ignoring impossible?

Answer (score 0):

## Python regex is cool

Python does support negative **lookahead** lookups `(?=.*foo)`. But it doesn't support arbitrary-length negative lookbehind lookups `(?<=foo.*)`. It needs to be fixed `(?<=foo..)`.

Which means it's definitely possible to solve your problem.

## The problem

You've got the following regex: `/customer/(?!.*/data/.*).*`.
Let's take an input example `/customer/data/name`. It matches for a reason.

```
/customer/data/name
^^^^^^^^^^ -> /customer/ match !
          ^ (?!.*/data/.*) Let's check if there is no /data/ ahead
             The problem is here, we've already matched "/"
             so the regex only finds "data/name" instead of "/data/name"
          ^^^^^^^^^ .* match !
```

## Fixing your regex

Basically we just need to remove that one forward slash, we add an anchor `^` to make sure it's the beginning of string and make sure we just match `customer` by using `\b` : `^/customer\b(?!.*/data/).*`.

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nW5hQ9)</kbd>

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. 
my folder contains a folder for different customers which can again contain datafolders somewhere inside. Theoretically my regexp should match those.
I tried to fix the left side like you did like this:
    ^site/customer/\b(?!.*/data/.*).*
But it does not work either.

Comment: @Niksac Please provide a [regex101](http://regex101.com) demo. Also note that I used `^/customer\b(?!.*/data/).*` and not `^site/customer/\b(?!.*/data/.*).*`. (You've added the forwardslash)

Comment: @Niksac You're still adding `/` after `customer` ... *sigh* Try removing `^`. I'm not familiar with `hg` ...

Comment: Hey HamZa. As the data folders are never a direct subfolder of "customer" adding the "/" is actually beneficial because otherwise i cannot have folders starting with "customer" anymore.
I tested "^site/customer/.*$" and it matches all files so this part of the rule should be correct.
I guess its a hg thing

Comment: @Niksac Sorry but I can't help you further. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2247110), negative lookahead definitely works in hg.